# Stupid simple: How to print {{Str}} in laravel blade engine?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

1.Expected output:

```
{{_STR_}}
```

2.My input :

```
 echo ('{{_STR_}}');
```

3.How to print the short code {{}} in laravel blade engine?

4.However, I want to print the

```
 {{_STR_}}
```

without using the echo . any way to do it more clearly and simpler in blade engine?

thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, then according to [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates):

> If you need to display a string that is wrapped in curly braces, you
>   may escape the Blade behavior by prefixing your text with an @ symbol:

```
@{{ This will not be processed by Blade }}
```

So for your example:

```
@{{_STR_}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can escape the Blade behaviour by prefixing with `@`:

```
@{{_STR_}}
```

This will tell Blade to output literal `{{_STR_}}` instead of looking for a variable.